# What is the duty of a Notary in interaction between chains ? (Updated)

Tags: sharding, terminology, cross-chain, cross-shard-transaction, interoperability

- What is the precise definition of **"Notary"** entity?
- Is the definition of "Notary" **the same** in "interoperability between different blockchains" AND "cross-shard transaction in a shared chain"? Or do we have **different types** of "Notary" ?
- What is the **duty** of a Notary? attesting "**availability** of a block" ? or "**validity** of state" ? **Which one ?**

**References:**

1. [Link](https://medium.com/nearprotocol/unsolved-problems-in-blockchain-sharding-2327d6517f43)
2. [Link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.01873.pdf)
3. [Link](https://www.eublockchainforum.eu/sites/default/files/research-paper/an_overview_of_blockchain_scalability_interoperability_and_sustainability.pdf?width=1024&height=800&iframe=true) (Page 9: Notary schemes)
4. [Link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8691432) (Page 3)
5. [Link](https://nearprotocol.com/downloads/Nightshade.pdf) (Page 18)
6. [Link](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3284769) (Page 5)

Comment: From your link Notary is a generic term used by similar protocols. As you said it is used to attest different things. Until Eth 2.0 protocol is set in stone is hard to answer your questions properly.